# cocoa:How to Get the toolbar 's Tag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

cocoa:How to Get the toolbar 's Tag?The AppController How to Get the toolbar 's Tag.

[image]
This is my `AppController.h` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject{
@private
    IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
    IBOutlet WebView *webViewm;
}
-(IBAction)toolbarAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is my `AppController.m` file

```
#import "AppController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppController

-(IBAction)toolbarAction:(id)sender{

   // NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]init] ;
    [label setStringValue:[sender label]];


    NSString *urls=[[NSString alloc] init];

  //  WebView *webView = [(AppWindow *)self.superview.window webView];
    //NSToolbar *toolbar=[(AppDelegate *)self.superview.window
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
    [webViewm setMainFrameURL:@"http://www.baidu.com"];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSToolbarItem` has a `-(NSInteger)tag`, so you can just do `[item tag]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(IBAction)toolbarAction:(id)sender{
    UIToolBar*toolBar=(UIToolBar*)sender.superView;
    int tag=toolBar.tag;
}
```

EDIT: that is in case that the sender is a button inside the toolbar, otherwise do sender.tag